# How to animate a dotted ripple affect for android

Tags: android, android-animation, circular-dependency, ripple-effect

I have a circular image which has to be animated to simulate a ripple effect.(Dotted circle)

I have seen a lot of third party libraries that can be used for animation. I want to do it without using any third party libraries.

Can you please suggest me how do we do it?

Comment: You want animation happens when? Clicking or loading. Please elaborate

Comment: I want the animation on loading